# Permissions on "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory disappear overnite

Tags: asp.net, permission-denied, ghosts-in-the-machine

Every morning, I get the same error:

> The current identity (myMachine\ASPNET) does not have write access to 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

I re-add the permissions, and everything works for the day.  This appears to happens whether or not I reboot.

I can't find any scheduled task that might be making these changes, and it doesn't happen to all the machines in my dev group, just some of them, so I don't think its something being pushed out via a group policy.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: Similar to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85941/aspnet-user-does-not-have-write-access-to-temporary-asp-net-files">this question</a>?

Comment: That question seemed like it was a one-time thing.  I haven't done a re-install, or otherwise modified my installation - my permissions are going away with no explanation.

Comment: Maybe something is delete your directory for clear the temp (rare but... you never know) ? and he lose the permissions. After you see it again have get the permission from father ? or have his won one.

Comment: I thought about that, but a lot of the files in the temp directory are old, so I don't think the directory is getting deleted & recreated.